# ASPX Form not calling codebehind on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm facing a rather odd behaviour that I can't explain myself. I have the following form on one of my ASP.net page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Codebehind.aspx.cs" Inherits="Myclass.Test" %>
<form name="application" id="application" method="post">
<asp:Table runat="server" width="840" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tbl_test">
...
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlign="Center" style="padding-top:10px">
<asp:Button onClick="Click" ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit!" Height="30" Width="150" />
</asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

In the aspx.cs assembly I have a protected function "Click" that should get fired once the user clicks the button in the form. However, it does not. Nothing happens, I press the button and the function in my codebehind never gets to do its thing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Kenneth is correct.  Voting to close as "too localized", since this is just a typo more or less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `runat="server"` attribute on the form

Comment: I already have another form on the website with the runat="server" attribute. If I add this attribute I encounter another error message that a page can only have one form with runat="server".

Comment: Then at least you need to set the Action-attribute of your form. In that case no click-events will be raised though. ASP.NET web forms really only fully supports a single form per page because of it's desktop-like programming model. (Yes, stupid, I know). If you want a solution closer to real HTTP and browser way of doing things, you should look into ASP.NET MVC, but I guess this is probably not possible

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a form with validations? If yes, use

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" onClick="Click" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="false" />
```